# Metadata Info on video file.. Pls Advise

Tags: metadata

I have a question on metadata on video files.. Can metadata tracks the last user who download a video file from sources with the relevant date and time information?

Say if a video was downloaded to my local computer...  Subsequently it was copied to another hdd and computer..  Can metadata tells or track the last user of this video files?

If yes how was it done and how to find the info?  I know words or excel does track the original author and subsequent user who saved and modified the doc.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer is no, you cannot track the last user of a video file by the metadata.  There's no OS mechanism to insert this data as it gets copied or moved from computer to computer.

Comment: Thnks mate.. As a matter of fact..  I had a video file that i do not know the sources from in my company folder..  And they found this video as a violation.. Is there a way to track who and when or when this was last use by who? How to apply forensic on this?

Comment: That's beyond my expertise but I believe that there should be something in regards to the filesystem that should tell what user uploaded it.  It depends upon the system.  For example on a Windows network server, you could try [how to find out what created a file?](https://serverfault.com/questions/20668/how-to-find-out-what-created-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

Oh ok. So within the video file itself we cannot tell the last source used and also the origin? I was trying to find out some clue that may presence , ie who last use it and downloaded it